# Derby Transactions BEGIN and END

Tags: java, derby

I created a trigger which works fine.

```
CREATE TRIGGER INSERT_USERID_TO_PERMISSIONS_TABLES
    AFTER INSERT ON ALLUSERS
        REFERENCING NEW AS NEW_USERID_ROW
        FOR EACH ROW MODE DB2SQL
            INSERT INTO ALLUSERS_HOMEPERMISSIONS(USERID)
            VALUES(NEW_USERID_ROW.USERID);
```

Then I dropped it to recreate a new version of it that has 2 `INSERT` statements. When I added the other `INSERT` statement, it fails and returns an error. I know there's just some syntax error or keyword I missed. I googled it but can't get the equivalent of `BEGIN and END` (in MSSQL) for Derby.

So if I do,

```
CREATE TRIGGER INSERT_USERID_TO_PERMISSIONS_TABLES
    AFTER INSERT ON ALLUSERS
        REFERENCING NEW AS NEW_USERID_ROW
        FOR EACH ROW MODE DB2SQL
            INSERT INTO ALLUSERS_HOMEPERMISSIONS(USERID) --1st insert
            VALUES(NEW_USERID_ROW.USERID);

            INSERT INTO ALLUSERS_ADMIN_PERMISSIONS(USERID)-- 2nd insert
            VALUES(NEW_USERID_ROW.USERID);
```

it returns an error.

I thought maybe I can add `BEGIN` and `END`

```
CREATE TRIGGER INSERT_USERID_TO_PERMISSIONS_TABLES
    AFTER INSERT ON ALLUSERS
        REFERENCING NEW AS NEW_USERID_ROW
        FOR EACH ROW MODE DB2SQL
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO ALLUSERS_HOMEPERMISSIONS(USERID) --1st insert
            VALUES(NEW_USERID_ROW.USERID);

            INSERT INTO ALLUSERS_ADMIN_PERMISSIONS(USERID)-- 2nd insert
            VALUES(NEW_USERID_ROW.USERID); 
       END
```

[image]

I'd appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: so what error DO you get?

Comment: @MarcB I doesn't return the error code on Netbeans. I've added the exact trigger definition where I'm having problems with and edited the post. I hope you can help.